# LinearSVC not classifying the sentiment correctly

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to make a sentiment analyser using the scikit-learn LinearSVC classifier. The problem is that the classifier is classifying every sentence as a positive. Another question is - why is the function predict() returning me a list of the classified label for every text? I thought that it should return only one text/number which is the classified label. Here is a sample cut from the code.

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(input='content', decode_error='ignore')
vect_train_x = vectorizer.fit_transform(training_data) # this is actually a list of sentences

scaler = StandardScaler(with_mean=False) # I don't know why it should be False
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(vect_train_x)  # compute mean, std and transform training data as well

vect_test_x = vectorizer.transform(test) # the sentence that needs to be classified

X_test = scaler.transform(vect_test_x) 

clf = LinearSVC()
clf.fit(X_train, labels)
print vect_test_x
print clf.predict(X_test) # returning me a list of Positive => ['Positive' 'Positive' 'Positive' 'Positive' 'Positive' 'Positive']
```

I would be very grateful if you explain me what exactly I am not understanding. I tried to read the documentation but without any examples I could not understand it. My training data consists of 100 000 positive and 100 000 negative sentences.

Comment: How large is your training data? Can you provide that?

Comment: Yes, My training data contains 100,000 positive and 100,000 negative sentences.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this, I had the same issue, what solved my problem was to convert X_test to a list first, then to np.array which then needs to be pass to the 'predict' function

```
new_array = []
new_array.append(Input) #Input is string if reading from a file or from input()
X_test = np.array(new_array)
print clf.predict(X_test)
```